# How to compare two identical values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

```
@Var1=CHA000375972
@Var2=CHA000375972
@Var2=000375972
```

Here `@Var1` and `@Var2` are completely the same, but `@Var3` is identical to `@Var1` or `@Var2`. So how can we compare if two values look identical?

Here my goal is to get all values whether its complete same or almost same

```
select distinct a.SupplierInvoiceNumber
from #tmpSup1 a  
join #tmpSup2 b on a.SupplierInvoiceNumber = b.SupplierInvoiceNumber
```

Comment: `@var2 like '%' + @var3 + '%'`  and vice versa.

Comment: Is your final row supposed to be `@Var3` rather than `@Var2`? Doesn't look identical to the previous values if so. what distinction are you making between "completely same" and "looks identical"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compare the right most 9 characters, you can use this:

```
right(@Var1,9) = right(@Var3,9)

select distinct a.SupplierInvoiceNumber
  from #tmpSup1 a 
    join #tmpSup2 b on right(a.SupplierInvoiceNumber,9)=right(b.SupplierInvoiceNumber,9)
```

If only one table has the SupplierInvoiceNumbers that are longer than 9 characters would need to be in the right() function the join condition could be simplified to:

```
    join #tmpSup2 b on right(a.SupplierInvoiceNumber,9)=b.SupplierInvoiceNumber
```

or

```
    join #tmpSup2 b on a.SupplierInvoiceNumber=right(b.SupplierInvoiceNumber)
```

If one variable is always shorter than the other, but not always 9 characters, you can use this:

```
select distinct a.SupplierInvoiceNumber
  from #tmpSup1 a 
    join #tmpSup2 b on a.SupplierInvoiceNumber like '%'+b.SupplierInvoiceNumber
```